# Accessing object attributes and methods from other modules

Tags: python, python-import, python-class

I have a GUI application I've been developing as an exercise in Python. The application is structured as a package. I initially create an instance of the application, which creates an instance of a window, which contains layouts, which contain buttons, text boxes, etc... Each class is defined in it's own module.

What I'm trying to do is have a button click call a method or modify an attribute that belongs to one of the higher level containing objects, say the window object. Sort of like below

```
class object_3():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fire(self):
        topObject.foo()

class object_2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.subObject = object_3()

class object_1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = object_2()
    def foo(self):
        print("Hello world")

topObject = object_1()
```

In this case, subObject's fire method would be called on a click event. Obviously, as written this code functions. But, if you split this code up into multiple modules it does not. I'm trying to understand the right way to approach this problem.

Up till now, my solution has been passing object references down the chain of objects. Like this:

```
# Module C
class object_3():
    def __init__(self, parentRef):
        self.parentRef = parentRef
    def fire(self):
        self.parentRef.foo()

#Module B
import moduleC
class object_2():
    def __init__(self, parentRef):
        self.parentRef = parentRef
        self.subObject = moduleC.object_3(self.parentRef)

#Module A
import moduleB
class object_1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = moduleB.object_2(self)
    def foo(self):
        print("Hello world")

topObject = object_1()
```

This totally works but I read somewhere that this was poor practice. It also strikes me as a cumbersome solution for more than a level or two.

Doing some research, it seems that one approach is to import the module that instantiates the object you're trying to interact with. If I modify the Module C code above...

```
# Module C
class object_3():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fire(self):
        import moduleA
        moduleA.topObject.foo()
```

However, when I tried this in practice I ran into other errors especially with PyQT event loops. This may be the correct approach and the errors are due to my poor implementation of other parts of the code, but I suppose that's what I'm asking

What's the correct approach to this problem? Is the reference passing approach fine, even though it seems really ugly. Is importing the right way to go, and I need to resolve the other issues that generates in my application? Or, have I completely wandered down a dark alley here and I shouldn't even be trying to do this?

Comment: From my point of view, passing references down the chain is the way to go. What would be your breaking cases? Can you link the "somewhere" you read it was poor practice?

Comment: I updated my question because I actually couldn’t think of a time it broke. I suppose I just found it cumbersome, but also realized I was passing a bunch of references when I could have just passed the highest object’s reference and used dot notation to access the other objects.  
I’ll see if I can find the comment about it being bad practice; it was a comment on another question I found but didn’t save. I believe it had to do with garbage collection, but I’m really unfamiliar with that topic.